# Is it possible to reuse a double quoted string with variables?

Tags: php

The application I'm writing generates some HTML server side though it could be applied to just any string.

```
$badges = [
    "<span class='badge badge--brand badge--inline'>$target</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--dark badge--inline'>$target</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--primary badge--inline'>$target</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--success badge--inline'>$target</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--info badge--inline'>$target</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--warning badge--inline'>$target</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--danger badge--inline'>$target</span>",
];

$TargetStr = 'one,two,three';

$Targets = explode(',', $TargetStr);
$Badges = '';
foreach ($Targets as $index => $target) {
    $Badges .= $badges[$index % count($badges)];
}
echo $Badges;
```

The desired output would be:

```
<span class='badge badge--brand badge--inline'>one</span><span class='badge badge--dark badge--inline'>two</span><span class='badge badge--primary badge--inline'>three</span>
```

I realize the `$target` variables are being evaluated inside the array, before it reaches the loop. With error reporting, this fails and without it, there is nothing in place of `$target`.

I can certainly just leverage `str_replace` and achieve desired results but this seemed like an interesting solution if I could get it to work.

Is it possible to achieve this? I haven't tried using `eval` and I would prefer not to as the `$TargetStr` is user supplied.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Can you give an expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set these spans as format strings instead.

```
$badges = [
    "<span class='badge badge--brand badge--inline'>%s</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--dark badge--inline'>%s</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--primary badge--inline'>%s</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--success badge--inline'>%s</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--info badge--inline'>%s</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--warning badge--inline'>%s</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--danger badge--inline'>%s</span>",
];
```

Then use [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to print the spans with your variables.

```
$TargetStr = 'one,two,three';

$Targets = explode(',', $TargetStr);
$Badges = '';
foreach ($Targets as $index => $target) {
    $Badges .= sprintf($badges[$index % count($badges)], $target);
}
echo $Badges;
```

---

If you like, you could also use `sprintf()` to insert the different badge types to eliminate the repeated markup.

```
$badges = ['brand', 'dark', 'primary', 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger'];
$span = "<span class='badge badge--%s badge--inline'>%s</span>";

$TargetStr = 'one,two,three';

$Targets = explode(',', $TargetStr);
$Badges = '';
foreach ($Targets as $index => $target) {
    $Badges .= sprintf($span, $badges[$index % count($badges)], $target);
}
echo $Badges;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer this:

```
$badges = [
    "<span class='badge badge--brand badge--inline'>{{target}}</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--dark badge--inline'>{{target}}</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--primary badge--inline'>{{target}}</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--success badge--inline'>{{target}}</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--info badge--inline'>{{target}}</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--warning badge--inline'>{{target}}</span>",
    "<span class='badge badge--danger badge--inline'>{{target}}</span>",
];

$TargetStr = 'one,two,three';

$Targets = explode(',', $TargetStr);
$Badges = '';
foreach ($Targets as $index => $target) {
    $Badges .= str_replace('{{target}}', $target, $badges[$index % count($badges)]);
}
echo $Badges;
```

eval solution (tested / Working):

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!
$badges = [
    '<span class="badge badge--brand badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--dark badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--primary badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--success badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--info badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--warning badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--danger badge--inline">$target</span>',
];

$TargetStr = 'one,two,three';

$Targets = explode(',', $TargetStr);
$Badges = '';
foreach ($Targets as $index => $target) {
    $Badges .= eval(" ?>".preg_replace('/>([^<]+)</', '><?php echo $1; ?><', $badges[$index % count($badges)]). "<?php ");
}
echo $Badges;
```

Comment: yeah that is how I have it in my code. At this point, this is just a mental exercise for me and a chance to learn PHP more. Thought it would be interesting to try and get it to work with the variables

Comment: Notice, its only working, if your variable is between the tags.

Comment: [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) would probably be a better choice than `eval` or `str_replace`.

Answer (score -2):

this works better, I think:

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!
$badges = [
    '<span class="badge badge--brand badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--dark badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--primary badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--success badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--info badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--warning badge--inline">$target</span>',
    '<span class="badge badge--danger badge--inline">$target</span>',
];

$TargetStr = 'one,two,three';

$Targets = explode(',', $TargetStr);
$Badges = '';
foreach ($Targets as $index => $target) {
    $Badges .= eval(" ?>".preg_replace('/(\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)/', '<?php echo $1; ?>', $badges[$index % count($badges)]). "<?php ");
}
echo $Badges;
```